# Why were all rows deleted when trying to delete old rows with date query

Tags: sql, postgresql, date, where-clause

I have a table with column name `date` of type `timestamp`

I'm trying to delete old rows with the following query:

```
delete from my_table where date<(now()-'30 days'::interval)
```

but all rows are deleted.

For example suppose I have a table with 2 rows:

```
date
2020-02-07 13:53:12.000
2020-02-09 09:30:12.000
```

I expect that the query will delete the first row (`now=02 sep 2020 - 30 days = 02 aug 2020`)
but all rows where deleted

How to fix the query to remove the rows I want?

Comment: What do you expect? Both rows are in February which is clearly before 2020-08-02 (btw: `'2020-09-02' - interval '30 days'` yields August **3rd**, not 2nd)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard formatting is `YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS:MS`. Both dates are in February, so they are earlier than August the second. You've probably meant to check against `2020-09-02 09:30:12.000` etc. More information you can find in the [official documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-formatting.html).